What is the significance of a vessel when washing hands?
What is the significance of the vessel when washing hands ritualistically (i.e. when waking up and before eating bread)? Why isn't washing hands in a sink under running water with soap sufficient?

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/orach-chaim/prayer-and-blessings/siman-1591-7-need-vessel&ved=2ahUKEwiRmpyu0bCFAxVGg4kEHZBFBMMQFnoECBgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2Jdwee2VBJFATdYudyS3Ka

I heard in a shiur that the significance of the kos (vessel) is that it represents the difference between chochma (creative intelligence*) and daat (wisdom and knowledge*). The former is likened to flowing water, the latter is likened to water sitting still in a kos.
One of the secrets of this mitzva is that it is associated with the concept of using our intellect to improve our middot (emotions and character traits, represented by the hands). As I wrote here, being insensitive to the needs and feelings of others is symbolised by the nails, as they are a dead and insensitive part of our body, and therefore we are symbollically washing away that insensitivity.
Another inyan is that our emotions and middot are produced by our intellect.
So, the answer to your question is, when it comes to producing good middot, we should do it with daat, rather than chochma. Chochma only produces fake and immature emotions, and this is why the stereotypical "genius" is such a nerd.
The Chochma needs to be "wisened". It needs to sit, become deeply absorbed, and personalised. Then it will produce deep, true emotions and middot.
* These are Kabbalistic terms and so therefore view their translations as very rough, to get the thought started.

"The former is likened to flowing water, the latter is likened to water sitting still in a kos." The immediate (and intermediate) analogy is mikva and maayan. Water held in a cup can be called a mikvah of sorts, or more formally, כעין דאורייתא תיקון that we purify ourselves using a significant collection of water.
